# Adding navigation properties EF Core .NET Core 3.1 - CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-core-3.1, navigation-properties

I have the following two tables:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
    public ApplicationUser RegisteredPerson { get; set; }        
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    ...
    public Person Person { get; set; }        
}
```

When creating a new migration to add the navigation properties, the following migration code is produced:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_AspNetUsers_PersonId",
    table: "AspNetUsers",
    column: "PersonId",
    unique: true);

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_AspNetUsers_Persons_PersonId",
    table: "AspNetUsers",
    column: "PersonId",
    principalTable: "Persons",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

I get the following error when trying to update the database with the new migration

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_AspNetUsers_PersonId] ON [AspNetUsers] ([PersonId]);

The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' and the index name 'IX_AspNetUsers_PersonId'. The duplicate key value is (0).
```

Suggestions for fix appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The issue is that your AspNetUsers table at that point already has a PersonId that was declared as non-null-able so when it would be added to the table it would default to 0 for every person user record. EF cannot set it up a unique index on that column. You will need to ensure every existing Users record has a unique PersonId set before you can apply that constraint.

Comment: Hi @StevePy. Thanks for the explanation, I see it makes sense now. As EF created that migration can I just simply set the unique constraint to false, as the PersonId column will contain 0 when I'm not linking to a Person in the Persons table, as AspNetUsers table can contain users not associated with the Persons table. Thanks

Comment: If the Person is optional then I'd suggest making PersonId null-able (`int?`) rather than 0. That way EF can maintain a FK, it is just recognized as optional.